# committing multiple connections during a transaction

Tags: java, connection, weblogic

can i create multiple connections during one transaction and perform commit on them provided the connection are taken from data source in weblogic. ??? please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean from different datasource?

Of course you can.  That's what JTA are for.

Just make sure that involved datasources' driver are XA-awared.

---

Edited
I got what you mean.

The application I developed has such feature.  Assume you have some basic flow control or handler structure for your request processing routine, you can always start a new transaction just for the error handling part, commit that new tranasction, and rollback the original one.

With Spring + Declarative transaction control you need to have a transaction declared around the error handling routine, with a REQUIRES_NEW propagation policy

Comment: hi Adrian... if my datasource is not XA-awared.. then will there be any problem.

Comment: Well yes ... unless you have some other way to perform two-phase commit across the "enlisted" data sources for a transaction.

Comment: i mean.. suppose i am using hibernate and data source as connection provider.. but for one case i need to rollback the complete execution.. but want to insert into one table with the time .. and some details... i thought to use connection from data source and use the simple process to insert into the table using PreparedStatement... will there be any problem regarding connection..

Comment: Do you mean an autonomous transaction to record the failure before rolling back?

Comment: @Mrityunjay: I don't see the difference between your case and some very normal case of having multiple insert/update/delete within the same transaction

Comment: @Alex yes. this is what i want to achieve..just record the failure before complete rollback..

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment that you want, effectively, an autonomous transaction to log a failure, you can either use a second connection from your datasource and commit that while rolling back the original failed one (which doesn't require XA; the wording in your question suggests you want to commit both connections simultaneously); or if you can use an actual [autonomous transaction](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10743/transact.htm#i7733) to handle the logging inside your original connection before rolling back. This is probably simpler and cleaner, particularly if your failure is really coming from a package call anyway as it can be dealt with as the failure occurs rather than having the client worry about it. In outline:

```
PROCEDURE log_failure(...)
IS
    PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
    insert ...
    commit;
END log_failure;
```